# Amazon RDS Unknown MYSQL Host

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I've been trying to connect to an RDS database from an application I'm hosting on elastic beanstalk.  It gives me this error:

```
[Instance: i-0f0051f7599e17190] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 
Output: (TRUNCATED)... -s /bin/bash -c 'leader_only bundle exec rake 
db:migrate' webapp rake aborted! Mysql2::Error: Unknown MySQL server host 
'xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (25) Tasks: TOP => 
 db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace). Hook 
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh failed. For 
more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

The server host is the correct hostname of the database, I just x'd it out.
I am able to connect to and view this database via the MYSQL workbench but not on localhost or AWS.  I've tried putting the host in manually rather than using a variable but that gave me the same error

Here is where I try to connect in my database.yml file

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

I've also tried messing around with the security groups but nothing really changes

When I try to connect on localhost it gives me

MYSQL2 Error
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: Is your RDS databse in a VPC?

Comment: "I am able to connect to and view this database via the MYSQL workbench but not on localhost or AWS" If you can't connect from localhost or AWS then where are you running MySQL Workbench that you can connect from?

Comment: Also, this is most likely a Security Group issue. Look at your Security Groups and if you can't figure it out, post your SG settings here.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure of the settings on the VPC but I think it is in one by default

Comment: Do you have this line in your database.yml file socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock

Comment: My only security group setttings are inbound accept TCP traffic on port 3306 from all IPs and outbound accept all Protocol and IPs

Comment: Also I do not have that line in my database.yml file

Comment: And what about the security group for RDS? Does your EC2 instance security group present in the RDS security group?

Comment: Okay so I looked again and everything is in the same VPC and my Elastic Beanstalk environment only has one inbound rule for TCP traffic on port 80 and anything outbound.  Do I need to add a rule for the database?

Comment: Add rule everything for 3306 and then check

Comment: Didn't work, gave me the same error code, could it be that I need to refresh somethings after adding rules?

Comment: Also add your EC2 instance public IP address in RDS security group and then check

Comment: I thought the IP was assigned when the app launches, where would I find that?

Comment: Check this screenshot you will find the security groups for the RDS here https://www.dropbox.com/s/b37bd8t3xzz7v1s/SCSH.png?dl=0

Comment: Just got it, you were spot on with the security group, for some reason the environment wasn't in one but it's clone was.  I moved the app to the clone environment added the everything on 3306 rule and it connects now.  Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue is due to your EC2 instance is not having access to your MYSQL RDS. Please add the access and your app will start working. Please follow this guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.AuthorizingEC2

Comment: Whoever wrote the library code that returns "unknown host" when it actually means "connection timed out" should have their keyboard privileges permanently revoked.